# Use xFirefox resource to install Firefox from local installer exe to a machine not connected to the internet - PowerShell Desired State Config DSC

Tags: powershell, resources

I want to use PowerShell DSC to install the Firefox webbrowser. I'm looking at  [dsccommunity /
xFirefox](https://github.com/dsccommunity/xFirefox)  which shows the following. Based on what I'm seeing, it doesn't look like it, but has anyone ever used this resource to install Firefox from a local copy of the installer exe to a machine that's not connected to the internet? If so, how?

```
Resources

MSFT_xFirefox

Language: Specify the language of the browser to be installed. The default value is English.

VersionNumber: Specify the version number of the browser to be installed. By default, the latest version is installed.

OS: Specify the operating system on which the browser is to be installed. By default, the operating system is Windows.

MachineBits: Specifies the machine's operating system bit number. The default is x86.

LocalPath: The local path on the machine where the installation file should be downloaded.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code of [MSFT_xFirefox](https://github.com/dsccommunity/xFirefox/blob/dev/DSCResources/MSFT_xFirefox/MSFT_xFirefox.schema.psm1) is pretty straight forward.

```
Package Installer
{
    Ensure = "Present"
    Path = $LocalPath
    Name = "Mozilla Firefox " + $VersionNumber + " (" + $MachineBits + " " + $Language +")"
    ProductId = ''
    Arguments = "/SilentMode"
    DependsOn = "[xRemoteFile]Downloader"
}
```

It `DependsOn` another configuration which will always download the installer. Remove that line and provide the installer in `$LocalPath`.

Comment: Thank-you - I'll try it out. Perhaps you know the answer to this one: I should obtain and use the msi installer (and not the exe installer), correct?

Comment: The default `LocalPath` is `"$env:SystemDrive\Windows\DtlDownloads\Firefox Setup " + $VersionNumber +".exe"`.